# Oracle compare tables content which has pipe symbol

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following problems in oracle and looking for a solutions.
I want to compare two tables content, but the content format is differing to each other’s.

```
Table CANON
CAN
18102-75|18103-0|18104-88

Table DRUM
DR
18103-0
```

I have to compare this two tables and should get the result 18102-75 and 18104-88
Currently I have a Case stament simply using the equal to and it give odd result.

```
CASE WHEN (CANON .CAN =  DRUM .DR) 
    THEN NULL -- not showing if they are the same 
    ELSE  CANON .CAN
END
```

Comment: Are you always looking for what is in CANON but not in DRUM? (not the other way around) Also just to understand this better, is the first identifier ('18102-75') for a camera, with the next 2 being compatible drums? Would it follow the same format on all rows of CANON; the first ID being the camera and then each compatible drum separated by a pipe?

Comment: Yes I wanted to fetch the data from CANON table. Some times the Canon have only single digit CAN no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
select *
  from (select substr(can, 1, instr(can, '|', 1, 1) - 1) as can,
               case
                 when level = 1 then
                  replace(substr(can, 1, instr(can, '|', 1, 1)), '|', '')
                 else
                  replace(substr(can,
                                 instr(can, '|', 1, level),
                                 length(can) - instr(can, '|', 1, level)),
                          '|',
                          '')
               end as drum
          from canon
        connect by level <= (length(can) - length(replace(can, '|')))
               and prior sys_guid() is not null
               and prior can = can) x
 where not exists (select 'x' from drum y where y.dr = x.drum)
 order by 1, 2
```

SQL Fiddle Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59a7b/1/0

**Note:** I added a 2nd row on each of your 2 tables for test purposes, as I wanted to make sure it worked for 2+ rows, since the logic is sensitive to that.

As a 2nd answer to your question, if you wanted the data on the same row (although I think my first query makes more sense), this would give you the exact result you asked for (putting the values all onto the same row for each value of CAN):

```
select can||'|'||listagg(drum,'|') within group (order by drum) as listed
  from (select substr(can, 1, instr(can, '|', 1, 1) - 1) as can,
               case
                 when level = 1 then
                  replace(substr(can, 1, instr(can, '|', 1, 1)), '|', '')
                 else
                  replace(substr(can,
                                 instr(can, '|', 1, level),
                                 length(can) - instr(can, '|', 1, level)),
                          '|',
                          '')
               end as drum
          from canon
        connect by level <= (length(can) - length(replace(can, '|')))
               and prior sys_guid() is not null
               and prior can = can) x
 where not exists (select 'x' from drum y where y.dr = x.drum)
group by can
order by 1
```

Comment: Note that this has each drum on a separate row in the result set. That is because to get your solution I had to break your single rows into multiple rows, which is probably how they should be stored anyway. If it's imperative you have them on the same row in the result set for any reason, you can use LISTAGG.

Comment: Just wondering will this work when there are more pipe delimited values?

Comment: Yes, the connect by clause is used to break the row into however many rows should be created as determined by the number of pipes in each string. So if there had been 5 drums on the row of CANON in your example, it would have made 5 rows for that row. On the next row if there were 3 in the delimited list, it would make 3.

Answer (score 0):

There's something that I don't understand... ;)

If you have more values in the same record, separate with "|" character, you can define - for example - a PL/SQL function that transform your string in a Table, and then use it in your query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_CHARACTERS_NESTED_TABLE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION STRING_TO_NESTED_TABLE
(pStringOfCharacters          IN   VARCHAR2)
RETURN T_CHARACTERS_NESTED_TABLE
PIPELINED
AS

   myStringOfCharacters   VARCHAR2(32767)   DEFAULT pStringOfCharacters || '|';
   myPos                  NUMBER;

BEGIN
   LOOP
      myPos := INSTR(myStringOfCharacters, '|');
      EXIT WHEN NVL(myPos, 0) = 0;

      PIPE ROW(TRIM(SUBSTR(myStringOfCharacters, 1, myPos - 1)));

      myStringOfCharacters := SUBSTR(myStringOfCharacters, myPos + 1);
   END LOOP;

   RETURN;

END STRING_TO_NESTED_TABLE;
/
```

And then:

```
SELECT CAN
FROM (SELECT T.COLUMN_VALUE AS CAN
      FROM CANON C,
           TABLE(STRING_TO_NESTED_TABLE(C.CAN)) T)
WHERE CAN NOT IN (SELECT DR
                  FROM DRUM
                  WHERE DR IS NOT NULL);
```

The condition "WHERE DR IS NOT NULL" in the subquery prevents you from getting an empty resultset, in case that you may have NULLs in DR column.